# $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ Cholesky decomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

*Mathematica* can do a Cholesky decomposition $\mathbf A = \mathbf L\mathbf L^\top$, but how do I do a LDL decomposition $\mathbf A = \mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$, with $\mathbf L$ being a unit lower triangular matrix?

Comment: Here is the  LAPACK [Fortran implemenation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/ssytrf.f.html) using what is called Bunch-Kaufman diagonal pivoting method for LDL^T factorization for real symmetric (not necessarily positive definite) matrix. I think Mathematica should have an LDL special decomposition. Matlab has one [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ldl.html).

Comment: @Nasser, in fact the $\mathbf D$ matrix in Bunch-Kaufman is *block diagonal* instead of being diagonal, so I wouldn't strictly consider it as something the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I needed this decomposition to answer another question, so I broke down and implemented it myself. The code is more or less a straightforward translation of the pseudocode in [Golub/Van Loan](http://books.google.com/books?id=X5YfsuCWpxMC&pg=PA158):

```
LDLT[mat_?SymmetricMatrixQ] := 
     Module[{n = Length[mat], mt = mat, v, w},
            Do[
               If[j > 1,
                  w = mt[[j, ;; j - 1]]; v = w Take[Diagonal[mt], j - 1];
                  mt[[j, j]] -= w.v;
                  If[j < n,
                     mt[[j + 1 ;;, j]] -= mt[[j + 1 ;;, ;; j - 1]].v]];
               mt[[j + 1 ;;, j]] /= mt[[j, j]],
               {j, n}];
            {LowerTriangularize[mt, -1] + IdentityMatrix[n], Diagonal[mt]}]
```

A few tests:

```
m1 = HilbertMatrix[20];
m2 = Array[Min, {20, 20}];

{l1, d1} = LDLT[m1];
m1 == l1.DiagonalMatrix[d1].Transpose[l1]
   True

{l2, d2} = LDLT[m2];
m2 == l2.DiagonalMatrix[d2].Transpose[l2]
   True
```

Comment: A variation for Hermitian matrices can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/214003).

Comment: Show how this algorithm works for a matrix containing symbols

Comment: You could try feeding it a symbolic matrix and study the output.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the word Conjugate? And yet, is it possible to display the matrix L and the matrix D separately?

Comment: The version here assumes a symmetric matrix (not a Hermitian one), so it *doesn't* use `Conjugate[]`. The $\mathbf L$ and $\mathbf D$ matrices are already separate, but are stored together in a list. If you evaluate `{l1, d1} = LDLT[m1];`, `l1` is the $\mathbf L$ factor, and `DiagonalMatrix[d1]` is the $\mathbf D$ factor.

Answer (score 10):

I'll illustrate with a simple example.

```
mat = {{2, 1}, {1, 3.}};
ch = CholeskyDecomposition[mat]

(* Out[145]= {{1.41421356237, 0.707106781187}, {0., 1.58113883008}} *)
```

Pull out the diagonal. Use it to modify and get a triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal.

```
diag = Diagonal[ch]

(* Out[148]= {1.41421356237, 1.58113883008} *)

modch = ch*1/diag

(* Out[149]= {{1., 0.5}, {0., 1.}} *)
```

Since we have to account for two such factors (one on each side), the `D` matrix will be the square of this diagonal. We check below that this gives the correct decomposition.

```
Transpose[modch].DiagonalMatrix[diag^2].modch

(* Out[153]= {{2., 1.}, {1., 3.}} *)
```

Comment: Cholesky decomposition does not apply to undetermined matrices while LDL does. Try `CholeskyDecomposition[{{1, 2}, {2, 1}}]`

Comment: @uranix means that a symmetric matrix that is not positive definite will certainly not have a Cholesky decomposition, but it may still have an $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ decomposition.