# How can I perform the modified Cholesky factorization/Decomposition in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

How to "Modified" Cholesky Decomposition in Mathematica?

what I mean:

V = L . D . Transpose[L]

V is p*p(row is p,columns is p) non-negative definite matrix,
D is diag[$d\small1$,$d\small2$,$d\small3$,$d\small4$...$d\small p$] (Diagonal Matrix),
L is Lower triangular matrix,whose diagonal component is 1.

I found [matlab package](https://github.com/higham/modified-cholesky) for example

---

OK,I've found that LDL factorization is called Modified Cholesky Decomposition.
[$\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ Cholesky decomposition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83469/mathbf-l-mathbf-d-mathbf-l-top-cholesky-decomposition/92502#92502)

---

built-in (but undocumented) function?
**Optimization`ModifiedCholeskyDecomposition**
[image]

Comment: What does "Modified" Cholesky Decomposition mean? Do you happen to mean $LDL^T$-factorization?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Given an example input, what do you expect to get out? Please try to provide more details in the future.

Comment: yes,it seems LDL$T$ factorization(I was confused). thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, Mathematica does not provide any built-in $LDL^T$-factorization. The factorizations provided by `LinearSolve` are $LU$-factorizations.